# How to set maximum read length for a stream in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream, stringstream

I'm reading data from a stream into a char array of a given length, and I'd like to make the maximum width of read to be large enough to fit in that char array.

The reason I use a char array is that part of my specification is that the length of any individual token cannot exceed a certain value, so I'm saving myself some constructor calls.

I thought width() did what I wanted, but I was apparently wrong...

EDIT: I'm using the stream extraction operators to perform the extraction, since these are flat text files with values separated by whitespace.

Comment: I don't understand. `istream::read()` lets you specify the amount of characters you want to read into a buffer. Why won't this work for you?

Comment: What I mean is that I want the extraction operators to limit themselves to a certain number of characters in length. The more I think about this, though, then more I realize this i probably not standard behavior...

Comment: Are your values all textual, or are some of them numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char x[4];
cin.width(4);
cin >> x;
cout << x;
```

Input: "abcdef"

Output: "abc"
(`x[3]` is null terminating char)

Width works fine in this case.

Note: Empirical testing indicates that the cin.width call only lasts for one stream operation.  It may be more convenient to use `cin >> setw(4) >> x;` instead, though this requires `iomanip`.

Comment: Note that if the input contains white-space this will fail.  Try it for Input: "a b c d e f".  Output: "a".

Comment: @Bill: I consider that a good thing.  The OP said that the values are separated by whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

If you're processing text, you're looking for the `get` function: http://cppreference.com/wiki/io/get

```
const int size = 200;
char myArray[size] = {};

cin.get(myArray, size);
```

Note: only `size - 1` characters are read, which leaves a NULL terminator in myArray.

If it's raw data, you'd probably prefer `read`: http://cppreference.com/wiki/io/read

```
const int size = 200;
char myArray[size] = {};

cin.read(myArray, size);
```

`size` bytes are read.